# How to determine if an electrical box is code-compliant/listed for non-permanent installation?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, code-compliance, extension-cord

I'd like to build a cord with a an 14-30P plug on one end and a 14-30R receptacle on the other end. I'll be using 8/4 SOOW cord.

Since there are no 14-30R receptacles designed to attach to the end of a cord that I can find, I believe I'll need a 2-gang electrical box with the appropriate cord connector. I've been reading that the usual electrical boxes with knockouts are not code compliant because they are only listed for permanent installation.

If I want to do this in a code compliant way, how would I find an electrical box that is listed for non-permanent installation, and then lookup it's listing to verify it is listed for that?

I'm having a hard enough time finding the UL listing for something to start with, let along finding something with a listing like I need.

I read [read](https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/ec384d28-b1db-4f5a-a8a7-4b7657f85811/downloads/1bo93cqsu_128804.pdf) that electrical boxes with threaded hubs are what I need for non-permanent installation. I found one item, Greenfield Industries B34PS (wrong width though), and I think I found the [applicable UL listing.](https://productiq.ulprospector.com/en/profile/3279004/qcit.e103697?term=Greenfield%20Industries&page=1)

How can I tell if this would be code compliant to use?

Comment: Are you just needing to extend NEMA 14-30 to NEMA 14-30, or are you looking to build some sort of adapter cord?

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the project a bit for the description. I was actually looking at making a cable that plugs in to a wall NEMA 14-30 receptacle and has an output of one NEMA 14-30 receptacle and one NEMA L14-30 receptacle. Essentially a splitter.

Once I saw the cost of cord grips that can take the 0.76" 8/4 cord, I decided it was better to just buy an NEMA 14-30 splitter off of Amazon (unfortunately not UL listed) since I already have a NEMA 14-30P to NEMA L14-30R cable anyways.

I'm still curious what the right way to find what something is listed for though.

Comment: Funny that you're worried about using a box (UL listed for permanent installation only) in a non-code compliant way and are looking for a code compliant alternative (good on ya' and well done!), yet you're satisfied with using a non-UL listed gadget from Amazon built who knows where by who knows who, just because one component of your compliant assembly was too much money.

Comment: What exactly "listing" or rules are we referring to when designing home made extension cords?  If you are not making it part of a building and not selling it, I do not know what compliance issues might exist.  A lot of things are not UL listed because it's not commercially viable to get them listed, not because they are inherently unsafe.  That doesn't mean you can't use common sense in building something safe for your own use.  I think the (one so far) answer here gives good advice to that effect and I wonder whether the parts of the question about compliance are irrelevant?

Comment: @FreeMan I see the irony you point out. Time also came into consideration. Same/lower cost and more time might be OK, but more cost and more time is hard to swallow. This is what I ended up buying (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07CVSSYQL). It says it uses 10/4 wire but who knows if that's correct. You pays your money and you takes your chances.

Comment: @jay613 I recognize your point that there is a distinction between "code compliant" and "safe to a high degree of confidence". This is a somewhat academic exercise of my trying to figure how I could be code compliant, whether or not I actually take that path. The PDF I linked says "NEC® Article
110.3(B) Installation and Use, which states that “listed or labeled equipment shall be installed and used in accordance with any instructions included in the listing or labeling.” My question was that I'm curious how to find a box for non-permanent installation that meets this criteria.

Comment: I like the spirit of your question but, whereas the NEC is about providing standards for people to build things, the UL standards are aimed at testing and certification.  There is definitively no way to knock together listed things into a listed object, perhaps with "inspection" in the style of a building project.  You have to undergo the full testing and cert process.

Comment: And if your question is just about finding the right components (and you'll take it from there), it devolves into "I'm looking for a box UL listed for unmounted electrical projects, either arbitrary ones or specifically for the tail end of a 7kW extension cord" .... that becomes a "shopping question" that won't last 3 hours here.  And nobody is going to UL-list a box specifically for use at the end of an obscure extension cord.  They'll make the cord and list that.

Comment: If you search for "UL Listed NEMA Enclosures" you find **loads** of them.  But when you dig in a little, the UL standards they are listed for tend to be for industrial control applications where certain types of protection are required, and it is that protection that has been certified.

Answer (score 3):

> Since there are no 14-30R receptacles designed to attach to the end of a cord that I can find

Use the "box" trick discussed in your link.

You don't need 8/4 *cordage* unless you have length well over 200' *and* loads near max amps a lot *and* loads intolerant of voltage drop.  Remember, don't calculate voltage drop on 30A. Calculate it on actual realistic loads.

10/4 *cordage* will be fine.  You made trouble for yourself by insisting on 8/4 as that is larger cord, and the strain reliefs on inline plugs/sockets aren't designed to fit it.

What isn't going to work is putting two 10/4 cords into one socket. They're not made for that.

> I [read](https://img1.wsimg.com/blobby/go/ec384d28-b1db-4f5a-a8a7-4b7657f85811/downloads/1bo93cqsu_128804.pdf) that electrical boxes with threaded hubs are what I need for non-permanent installation.

I completely concur with that writer's assessment of steel boxes *with pre-punched knockouts*. When abused as a extension cord box, yes - the KO's inevitably get KO'd lol.  But their idea of using non-KO-equipped boxes is fine IMO.  For your use with 2 sockets, 2 of those boxes "back to back" linked with short nipple(s) is the way to go. If I were using metal boxes, I'd use 4 short nipples simply for structural strength. The wires would go through **one** of them (NEC 300.3).

Their fear of metal boxes might be valid on a 30A adapter, given the huge number of ungrounded NEMA 10-30 sockets out there.

Costwise if there's a particular route this cord will always be found in, you may be better off hardwiring this to a stand/post with 6-6-6-6 aluminum *cable* (which is not available in flexible *cordage*) or #6Al individual conductors in conduit.  Note that FMC and IMC conduit, while costly, only needs 6" of cover burial depth.

While the homemade junction-box-cord idea may seem hokey, it's a hell of a lot more safe than any of that "cheap Cheese from overseas". You're lucky if they use #16 wire in that.

Comment: The OP's frustrations are understandable -- it doesn't seem that any of the "big names" (I checked Hubbell, Eaton/Arrow-Hart, Legrand, and Leviton) even *make* a female 14-30 cord connector for some odd reason, although L14-30 is fine...)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ouch... thanks.  I wonder why.

Comment: It's baffling, especially since 10-30 cord connectors exist, too...

Comment: Guessing, cord connectors are meant to be plugged in easily and conveniently with one hand (or with a male and female in both respective hands).   From memory, the barrel of a locking 14-30 is much smaller than the non-locking one would be if it existed in a barrel. It could not be easily gripped in one hand in the way that you do when plugging cords in.  A guess.

Comment: Also, a 14-30 *cord end* benefits so much from locking that maybe it's just a no brainer to use a locking one.  As opposed to one fixed to a wall behind a dryer, where locking may not solve any problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The reason for the 8/4 cord was because I already had it from a previous project where I was running it near max capacity over about 100'; and there's no kill like overkill! I see your point on that making life harder on myself though.

Comment: I really like the idea of two non-KO boxes back to back. That would mean I only need a single cord connector too. Any thoughts on how I could pick a non-KO box for this application that satisfies “listed or labeled equipment shall be installed and used in accordance with any instructions included in the listing or labeling.”?